# Which is the protocol through Apache communicates with database?

Tags: php

If database server is out of web server Apache communicates with database server through TCP/IP protocol, but when database and Apache is on the same computer which is the protocol by which they communicate?

Comment: I'm sorry, what's your question?

Comment: @njk - "when database and Apache is on the same computer which is the protocol by which they communicate?"

Comment: Depends on the database, I expect.

Comment: Is your question about Apache, as in the text, or PHP, as in the tag?

Comment: [link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/e4/0c6037a7160f449cf2929aaf753049/h-00100010000_image002.gif //case2

Answer (score 1):

The option exists for a number of database servers - on Unix/Linux-like operating systems (such as MySQL or PostgreSQL) to use a **[Unix socket file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)**. A Unix socket file connection is faster than TCP/IP, but can be used only when connecting to a server on the same computer. A Unix socket file is used if you do not specify a host name or if you specify the special host name `localhost`.

The socket file shows up as a special file in the file system (for MySQL, it defaults to /tmp/mysql.sock, unless that is altered in the server configuration).